# Adding dapr secretstore with local secrets file in helm deployment

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-helm, dapr

I face the following challange: We have a microservice application, which shall now be embedded into dapr. For simplicity, say we have Service A and B. Service A needs to know a secret to connect to B. A calls its sidecar (auto-injected via kubernetes attributes) which in turn finds the secretstore building block. Unfortunately, the secretstore is not able to find a local secrets file. We tried both relative and absolute pathes, in the first case we tested against various starting points (it is a bit nebulous from where in our scenario the relative path begins).

Background:

We use microk8s on a windows docker-desktop kubernetes cluster (4.9.1 with kubernetes 1.24). The deployment is managed with helm (3.8.2, also tried with 3.9.1). We also tested in a linux vm, same result, both absolute an relative pathes fail to be found.

Our Chart looks basically like this:

helm-app
--Service-A
----Charts
----Templates
------Deployment (with sidecar annots)
--Service-B
----Chart
----Templates
--Dapr
----Charts
----Templates
------Deployment (basically a dapr-component description)

Of course we searched the available docu for both helm and dapr but did find a similiar approach.

Any clue what we are doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Any luck? I think on Kubernetes you cannot link to a local file. You have to create a Kubernetes secret from the local file and pass that Kubernetes secret to Dapr. See here https://github.com/dapr/quickstarts/tree/master/tutorials/secretstore